# Actualizar primer campo firebase

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs, firebase

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    databaseURL: "https://visit-hotels.firebaseio.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var app = angular.module("nowtimereal", ["firebase"]);

// this factory returns a synchronized array of nowusers
app.factory("peopleNow", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {
    // create a reference to the database location where we will store our data
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('nowusers');

    // this uses AngularFire to create the synchronized array
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }
]);

app.controller("NowCtrl", ["$scope", "peopleNow", function($scope, nowPeople) {

   $scope.now = nowPeople;
   $scope.user = Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
   $scope.now.$save({
          count: $scope.user
    });

}]);
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo, no se si lo estoy haciendo mal o es un problema, pero quiero actualizar el primer item de la base de datos.

```
{
  "nowusers" : {
    "-L2LfbYxbwXDXiWNpt27" : {
      "count" : 13
    }
  }
}
```

estoy usando `angularfire` con el metodo $save, pero no me funciona tengo el siguiente error

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: Invalid record; could not determine key for [object Object]
```

Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias